# .ipa file install in device but won't open just blinks and quits

Tags: ios, objective-c, ipa, ad-hoc-distribution

.ipa file install in device but won't open just blinks and quits.This application is ad-hoc application. I added my device UDID in provisioning portal and make provisioning profile again and app successfully install but not open.

Comment: connect it with mac and run app from xcode and see what log display.

Comment: check your phone date..

Comment: It can be compatibility problem of your device and the app check your Build Settings, it cannot be UUID problem, otherwise the would have installed..

Answer (score 0):

Check your the build of the .ipa file verison.example your build lower version is ios6.0 but you ran on iPhone5 means it wont run .Please check it.